# Run Php Files When user is not online

Tags: php

I have a php file , For example `http://domain.com/user?id=uniquetoken` ,When user visits that url with unique token it does lots of stuffs using javascript and php and it takes atleast 2 minutes to complete a certain task.If the user is not patient and closes the window that task is not performed at all, What i need is when the user just visit `http://domain.com/user?id=token` , the task must me done in background.so even if user closes the window the task should be completed by php in backend,

I have some ideas like , file_get_contents, will that complete the task completely?Any ideas or suggestion please?

edit :
Somebody tell me if `file_get_contents(http://domain.com/user?id=token)` , another php file works? even after they close it immediately?? i have enabled  `ignore_user_abort().`

Comment: http://php.net/ignore_user_abort

Comment: this function is already there in php ini file,,there are lots of html files too.so it wont work

Comment: The Right Way to do this is to simply insert a task into a work queue like beanstalkd, and have a background worker pick it up.

Comment: hello frank ..it looks complicated...

Comment: will file_get_contents(http://domain.com/user?id=token) in another php file works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when user visits `http://domain.com/user?id=token` just call an `exec()` on the php script you want to run.

If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Once `exec()` is started with output redirection, it will continue to execute in server even if user closes the browser.

Comment: i have php files, with lots of iframes that does a task, will that too work in this method?

Comment: If what you are doing needs the script to be called through the `web browser` as opposed to command line `php`, use exec like so: `exec(path_to_browser http://path_to_php_script);`

Comment: wat is the path to the browser here ?

Comment: Are you running it linux or windows? If it is a "proper" server in linux then you might need to run it with lynx. You can check if it is installed and its path by using "whereis" or "which" command. In windows, it is just the path to your favorite browser's exe

Comment: no i will change it to pure php,, with some file_get_contents

Answer (score 0):

You can save all these urls somewhere, file or database, and use cron to run all these links.
If user didn't exit the page and the task is done - remove the link from the storage.